# How does vim color theme set highlight groups?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

Usually, I edit a highlight group like this:

```
hi typescriptAliasDeclaration guifg=#b58900
```

But when I look inside an `exampleColorTheme.vim`, I cannot see any mention of these highlight groups.

So how do color themes set and registor highlight groups in vim (not neovim)

UPDATE:

for example i use [Lucius theme](https://github.com/jonathanfilip/vim-lucius/blob/master/colors/lucius.vim) -- in the file there are no typescript highlight groups. But some of TS groups have colors.

Comment: The same way. Some times they define helper functions but ultimately it is the same API that is used.

Comment: Do you want to share the code?

Comment: I added an example theme i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is made of two things:

- A syntax definition, where regular expressions are used to define custom, filetype-specific "highlight groups". Ideally, those highlight groups should *all* be linked to a small number of generic highlight groups in order to simplify writing colorschemes.
- A colorscheme, where the generic highlight groups (at the very least) are given visual attributes like foreground color or weight.

In this specific case…

- the highlight group `typescriptAliasDeclaration` is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/shared/typescriptcommon.vim`,
- where it is linked to the generic highlight group `Identifier`,
- which any competently written colorscheme should handle out of the box.

--- EDIT ---

In the provided colorscheme, you can see how the author gives `Identifier` a foreground color:

```
hi Identifier   guifg=#00af00
```

which will be applied to every highlight group linked to `Identifier`, including `typescriptAliasDeclaration`.

Without that linking mechanism, colorschemes would need to explicitly include every single highlight group of every single filetype, which would make them unmaintainable.

Comment: That is an awesome explaination. Thank you so much.